# Set the path for mysql logging relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I'm trying to debug my prepared sql statements by turning on logging and I'm having trouble setting the path. If I do not include a path, the log file is created in the C:\xampp\mysql\data directory. When I try to specify a path either using `/logs/logfile.log` or including `document_root` as below, it does not work. Any suggestions to get the log file relative to the `SERVER` as opposed to relative to `mySQL`?

```
$q = 'SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE"';
$this->mysqli->query($q);
$q = 'SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/logs/logfile.log"';
$this->mysqli->query($q);
$q = 'SET GLOBAL general_log = "ON"';
$this->mysqli->query($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the slashes in Windows 7.

I had to replace backslashes with forward slashes as follows:

```
$q = 'SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "' . str_replace("\\", "/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/logs/error.log"'
```

All works as desired now.